# My CSS is not showing up

Tags: html, css

i know you have like 20 of these questions already but none of them seem to be in my case, the ones that seem to fit in my problem category don't help.

I will show my HTMLand my CSS scripts (these are just a tests but i re-checked the code and everything seems right)
also it seems to work on a HTML Notepad on the results but when i saved and i clicked the chrome icon on my desktop it didnt work.

```css
html {
    background-color:#373842;
}
h1 {
    font-family:Arial; color:white;text-decoration:underline;
}
img {
    border:1px solid white;
}
p {
    font-family:Arial;color:white;
}
h3 {
    font-family:Arial; color:white;text-decoration:underline;
}
li {
    font-family:Arial;color:white;
}
table, th, td {
    border:1px solid white;
}
th, td {
    padding:1px;color:white;
}
th {
    text-align:left;
}
caption {
    color:white;
}
h2 {
    font-family:Arial;color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Coding!</title>
        <link type=text/css rel=stylesheet href=Coding.css/>
    <body>
        <h1><em>Coding!</em></h1>
        <p>This is one of my most advanced HTML & CSS webpages!</p>
       <a href=www.smogon.com>
        <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/210717261084753920/308978986514645004/tumblr_o2x8zcNoFD1urr1ryo1_500.gif" 
        height="300" width="300"/>
        </a>
        <p>This is an amazing picture of clefairy/gengar in a creepy setting. If you click the picture, it will bring you to 
  smogon which is a Pokemon PvP Site. On this site you can find; Pokemon sets to use in PvP, Pokemon PvP Articles, a 
  damage calculator and much more!</p>
  <p>I plan to code Webpages, Games, Bots, Forums etc. much more when i master HTML, CSS and JavaScript. After this i plan to make webpages with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, make games with C++, and make forums with PHP.</p>
  <p>I am also looking for 1-4 people so i can make a small coding group, with them we would make games, webpages, forums etc. I know i said <strong>I</strong> would do these things in the future but coding is complex and it takes long to do (especially if you do it alone.) so if anyone knows how to code i would be greatful if we could make a group so you could help me with some of my projects.</p>
  <h3>What I Plan To Do:</h3>
  <ul>
      <li>Make A Pokemon Game</li>
      <li>Make A Website</li>
      <li>Make Another Game</li>
      <li>Make A Forum</li>
      <li>Make A Bot</li>
  </ul>
  <p>I will think of a lot of other cool ideas, but for now we will just stick with those ones and see how they work out.</p>
  <p>You may not believe this but this tiny webpage is actually a lot of code on HTML and CSS!</p>
  <table>
      <caption>Members of The Team</caption>
      <tr>
          <td>First Name</td>
          <td>Last Name</td>
          <td>Username</td>
          <td>Age</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Di Loni</td>
          <td>Di Lorenzo</td>
          <td>SH4RK1701 & TheProdigy</td>
          <td>15</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <p>Anyway that's all for now!</p>
  <h2>Cya Next Time!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is your demo here working like you expect it?

Comment: Although it's optional, I'd wrap all attribute values in quotes `"`.

Comment: `href=Coding.css` this is the css path?

Comment: Yes the demo is working as i expect it, and yes that is the path.
It works in HTML 5 Editor and it worked here, it just doesnt work in a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Close your `<head>` tag `</head>`:

```css
html {
  background-color: #373842;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

p {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

li {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 1px;
  color: white;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

caption {
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Coding!</title>
  <link type=text/css rel=stylesheet href=Coding.css/>
</head>

<body>
  <h1><em>Coding!</em></h1>
  <p>This is one of my most advanced HTML & CSS webpages!</p>
  <a href=www.smogon.com>
    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/210717261084753920/308978986514645004/tumblr_o2x8zcNoFD1urr1ryo1_500.gif" height="300" width="300" />
  </a>
  <p>This is an amazing picture of clefairy/gengar in a creepy setting. If you click the picture, it will bring you to smogon which is a Pokemon PvP Site. On this site you can find; Pokemon sets to use in PvP, Pokemon PvP Articles, a damage calculator and
    much more!</p>
  <p>I plan to code Webpages, Games, Bots, Forums etc. much more when i master HTML, CSS and JavaScript. After this i plan to make webpages with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, make games with C++, and make forums with PHP.</p>
  <p>I am also looking for 1-4 people so i can make a small coding group, with them we would make games, webpages, forums etc. I know i said <strong>I</strong> would do these things in the future but coding is complex and it takes long to do (especially
    if you do it alone.) so if anyone knows how to code i would be greatful if we could make a group so you could help me with some of my projects.</p>
  <h3>What I Plan To Do:</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Make A Pokemon Game</li>
    <li>Make A Website</li>
    <li>Make Another Game</li>
    <li>Make A Forum</li>
    <li>Make A Bot</li>
  </ul>
  <p>I will think of a lot of other cool ideas, but for now we will just stick with those ones and see how they work out.</p>
  <p>You may not believe this but this tiny webpage is actually a lot of code on HTML and CSS!</p>
  <table>
    <caption>Members of The Team</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td>Username</td>
      <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Di Loni</td>
      <td>Di Lorenzo</td>
      <td>SH4RK1701 & TheProdigy</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>Anyway that's all for now!</p>
  <h2>Cya Next Time!</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing tag for `head`. Also check your file names.

Comment: You should mention the which tag isn't being closed.

Comment: @hungerstar I did, but it didn't show up because I typed it as code LOL

Comment: You can use backticks **\`** around elements so they show up, `<head>`.

Comment: @hungerstar yeah I figured it out after it was too late :(

Comment: I closed my head tag like you said (guess i forgot it) and the css still doesn't show up in a webpage